# What's the light under an Asus motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I installed a new Asus z170-e motherboard today and it has a white light under the back edge of the motherboard that flashes constantly on and off about once per second or so.  I don't see it in the manual.  I'm just wondering what it is.  The motherboard presently seems to work fine, in spite of that light, and isn't showing any of the problem lights.

Comment: Maybe consider taking a picture of the board/location of the light. There might also be some small print near it to indicate what it does.

Answer (score 1):

#### It has a white light under the back edge of the motherboard that flashes

That would appear to be the **Audio LED Lighting**:

> These LEDs light up when the system is fully powered and operating. To change the 
>   behavior of the LEDs to still mode or breathing mode, refer to BIOS section 
>   2.6.8 Onboard Devices Configuration Audio LED Lighting for details
>
> [image]

...

> 2.6.8 Onboard Devices Configuration

...

> [image]

Source [Z170-E Manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/Z170-E/E10826_Z170-E_UM_WEB.pdf)

Comment: The location of the light is actually higher than that, closer to the center of the back edge of the motherboard.  And it's underneath the motherboard, not on top of it.  And the audio LED still has its factory default setting, which seems to imply it should not light up at all when the power is in standby mode.

Comment: Note that by the bottom of the motherboard I mean the side that has the connections between components, as opposed to the side that has the components themselves.  I.e. lay the motherboard flat on a table, then turn it over, to see the bottom side.  I'm mentioning this because of the ambiguity of the motherboard being installed vertically and the bottom being construed to be the end closest to the power supply, which is not what I meant by bottom.

Comment: And of course I mean the same thing by underneath and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that it indicates the power supply is connected.  But it seems strange to me, that such a bright and slowly flashing light would be used for that kind of indication.  And it seems strange that I can't find it in the manual.  Note that it happens even when the PC power is off, as long as the power supply itself has power.  Also, it's a different kind of light than the problem lights.  it's brighter, and white.  They're dimmer and colored.  They're on top of the motherboard.  It's on the bottom.